# ping timeout problem even http site exist

Tags: console

C:\Users\MitjaB>ping 89.212.252.73

Pinging 89.212.252.73 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

but i can see http:\89.212.252.73

Can someone help me why i can not ping my IP. I am using IIS 7.0
I want to ping my computer to see if is reachable or not.

Comment: sorry must add this post to superuser page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will likely need to enable ICMP in your network/firewall settings on your server.

Comment: Was just typing the same thing.  Agreed.

Comment: i alreay try to disable firewall to test if then works but it is the same. Must i enable ICMP in router?

Comment: did you check your network/firewall settings on the computer your pinging from as well?

Comment: i can ping second server which is not behind router.

Answer (score 0):

Some sys admins block pings for security through obscurity reasons, but it's a bit outdated now as attackers go straight for standard ports anyway.

So somewhere on the route someone is block ICMP packets; it might be your computer or any switch or router on the way.

Try a backtrace; on Windows use `tracert 89.212.252.73`